# How can i repeat css3 animation on click?

Tags: jquery, css

I create an element and on click I toggleClass .anim so when it is added the animation works but when it's removed the animation obviously doesn't work. How do I make it work everytime I click on this element ?

```
$( "<div/>", {
   "class": "test",
   text: "Click me!",
   click : function(){
   $(this).toggleClass('anim');
      }    
}).appendTo( "body" );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TomasRR/7jskthcm/15/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use only CSS3 for that, use `.test:not(:active)` selector instead of `.anim`:

CSS :

```
.test:not(:active) {
    animation-duration: .8s;  
    -webkit-animation-duration: .8s;

    animation-name: fadeIn;
    -webkit-animation-name: fadeIn; 

    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out; 
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out; 
}
```

JS :

```
$( "<div/>", {
    "class": "test",
    text: "Click me!"    
})
.appendTo( "body" );
```

**DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/7jskthcm/20/**

Comment: can you explain :not(:active)

Comment: `:active` is when the div has been clicked. When you mouseUp the div, it launch `div:not(:active)`.

Comment: In this example the animation has been triggered when the div has not active, the `:active` property is run between mouseDown and mouseUp, so the animation starts on each mouseup, i hope it's more clear. I don't speak english very well so it's difficult to make a clear explain.

Answer (score 1):

i don't know if its correct way but it worked :-

```
$( "<div/>", {
"class": "test",
text: "Click me!",
click : function(){
    var t=$(this);
    t.toggleClass('anim').promise().done(function(){    
        setTimeout(function(){
          t.removeClass().addClass('test');
        },800)
    });
}    
})
.appendTo( "body" );
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/asdasdasdas/7jskthcm/17/)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
var $div = $("<div/>").addClass("test").text("Click Me!").click(function() {
    $(this).removeClass("anim");
    $(this).addClass("anim");
})

$("body").append($div);
```

That should work.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use jQuery's [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) function. There it should be executed every time